# How to open files in Firemonkey regardless of MIME type

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

When Gmail's attachments are present:

- If the file is a txt file, a list of applications that can be opened is opened.
- If it is an image file, a list of applications that can open photos, photos, galleries, etc. is opened.

Assuming you know the path to a file that exists in Android locally, how can I implement this so I can open it by clicking on it?

On Windows, I used `ShellExcute()` to implement this feature.

It seems to be one of the ways native apps handle MIME type handling and Intent handling:

[Launch A URL Or Document On IOS and Android With Delphi Firemonkey](http://www.fmxexpress.com/launch-a-url-or-document-on-ios-and-android-with-delphi-firemonkey/)

I can not use the `_system()` function in Delphi 10.1, like this example?

```
_system (PAnsiChar('open ' + AnsiString(sCommand)));
```

I changed it as follows, according to 10.1 documentation:

```
_system (MarshaledAString ('open ' + sCommand));
```

When debugging, the method is executed, but there is no response.

Comment: I rolled back your edit because it changed the entire scope of your question, rendering the answer invalid. Since you have a new problem, you need to ask a new question.

Comment: @JerryDodge The problem is the same.
Missing a space in a question is just a misstyping :( thank you.

Comment: On second thought, I rolled back the rollback, seeing as the symptoms are the same.

Answer (score 1):

After `'open'`, you need a space, e.g. `'open '`

Comment: It was a mistake in the first question.
In the code, put it in space.
However, there was no response after executing the method. Thank you.